ACC Viewer 2D: coloring and selecting polylines
When we load any dwg file into the ACC viewer we want to be able to easily select (click) and color (theme) the polylines/polygons that represent spaces.
If you simply load a dwg the only way to select a Polyline in the graphic is by clicking exactly on the outline of the element - clicking on the inside of a polygon does not lead to it being selected. When a polyline is selected it is very hard to notice that it is selected because only the polyline changes its color and not the filling of it.
In the picture below I selected a polyline that describes the orange colored space (its outline is slightly blue now). I want the entire polyline to be filled.

This also means it is not possible to fill the entire polyline in one color using the setThemingColor.
When I try calling that function I don't notice any visible change of the space.
We solved this problem by editing the original dwg and adding Solid (or Hatches) on top of each polyline and that works nicely. We can click these hatches easily (by also clicking somewhere inside of it and not only the line itself) and color them properly.
This is an example of a selected hatched space:

Now we need a way without editing the drawing file itself. I could think of several options but I was wondering which one is possible and the easiest to do.

Is there a setting in the viewer I am missing that will allow this?
Could I add those hatches manually at runtime when the drawing is loaded ontop of each original polyline in the dwg?
I guess one could catch click events on the viewer and calculate inside of which element the user clicked and then select that element per api. This could work for the easier selection but wouldn’t solve the coloring problem…

Be aware that the filled polylines/hatches should be at the lowest level in the drawing so all of the other elements are not visibly blocked by it - this order should be defined in the drawing already.
As a bonus we would also be interested in having a similar solution for any kind of blocks:

Clicking is more important for the blocks than the filling of it so the 3rd solution might work for them.
How would I implement the above ideas - if they are possible? Or is there a better solution?

Sounds like you are creating your own viewer (seperate from the built in ACC/BIM Viewer), right?
Great, that's a good start.
If for some reason you absolutely need to customize the highlighting, selection and hovering behaviors, you may want to get access to the underlining shape geometry first.
Use this to do that:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/move-entities-2d-drawing
Next, use the edit2d class to recreate the geometry you want, and begin customizing the UI controls and behavior without effecting the underlining drawing.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-manual/

Hi Michael, thanks alot. Sad to hear that you don't support an easier selection/coloring natively. Selecting polylines is not very easy at the moment. I tried your approach but I am stuck in two places: firstly, I am loading the vertices using the VertexBufferReader. How can I find out which vertices of one fragment/mesh of e.g. a block belong to the same polyline? There seem to be several polylines belonging to the same fragment which leads to me connecting all of the normally seperate polylines. Do you have to use the index buffer for that? Do you have any resources on that?

And secondly, I took a look at the edit2D extension. It seems weird to me that there is no way to select these polygons except for activating the PolygonEditTool. Unfortunately, this will also allow the user to edit these polygons. Am I missing something? I feel like there should be a (default?) SelectionTool: when activated the user should be able to select a edit2D object (i.e. event thrown, color change, hovering colors). Seems like I have to implement it myself :(

Lastly, is there any way to change the z-Index of the inserted polygons/the layer it was inserted on? I would like the edit layer to lie right above the spaces meaning below the other blocks, texts etc. More specifically, I want each inserted polygon to be right above the element it should represent. Otherwise it is not possible to select the elements that are lying below that edit polygon at all anymore.
